# How to assign domain name to virtual hosts in wamp

Tags: php

I have domain name I want to know how to connect the domain name to my virtual host I'm new to this so plz answer easy understandable answers Thanks for reading and hopefully answering

I change hots file C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

127.0.0.1 www.test.com

and also change httpd-vhosts.conf D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra

ServerAdmin webmaster@test.org.in
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\test"
    ServerName test.org.in
    ErrorLog "logs/test.org.in-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test.org.in-access.log" common

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file

Here a small example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.mydns.local
ServerAlias www.mydns.local
DocumentRoot "E:\WWW_VM_SHARE\smarty_fe\public"
<Directory "E:\WWW_VM_SHARE\smarty_fe\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

More Information can be found here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/